# Diffusion of chemical with two near sources

Tags: netlogo

I have two patches that are located at low distance each other.
I put some chemical on each one, and then i run the command diffuse. What happens to the pathes that are between the two sources? Do the chemical of the first patch sum up to the chemical of the second?

Answer (score 1):

If there is no degradation, the sum of the neighboring patches' chemical and the original patch's chemical will be the original amount.

Depending on your diffusion rate, the neighboring patches' chemical amounts will vary.

Try programming it to convince yourself.

Comment: What do you mean with original amount?

Comment: If you set a patch to have 25 units of chemical, for example,  then diffuse the chemical.  The sum of all patches chemicals will be 25 if there is no degradation

Comment: So, let's assume that we have a world with two sources patches A and B that are close each other. A is loaded with m of chemical, B is loaded with n of chemical. After start diffusing, the two flow of chemical will meet in some patches. Will the chemical of those patches being made by the sum of part of the chemical flow of A plus B?. The total amount of chemical in the whole scenario will be n+m.

Comment: Yes. That's correct.  You can test this by programming it.